# WooThemes WooCommerce Wishlist Template Override

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I'm currently working with WooTheme's Woocommerce Wishlists plugin (https://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-wishlists/), and I need to be able to edit the templates without having to edit them everytime I update the plugin. I've been directed towards this page for doing the same for the Woocommerce plugin itself: https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/

How might I do the same type of thing for the Woocommerce Wishlists plugin? I've tried the same basic thing as in the tutorial above, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Your guidance would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The best way, if you don't find anything else, is to ask wooThemes support for your plugin ([opening a ticket](https://www.woothemes.com/my-account/tickets/), or adding a thread). If there is a way to put the templates in your active theme folder  they will tell you.

Comment: I did this, and they shot me the page I listed above. I got stuck at that point.

Comment: Ask again… tell them that you are already using woocommerce templates in your active theme folder, **and you need to know how and where you can add the plugin templates of the plugin to your active theme**…

Comment: I've done this, and they came back with the same article and telling me that I needed to pay a third party to do it for me. Which is frustrating, because I can do it, I simply need to know how.

Comment: What you can try is to copy the `template` folder from this plugin in 2 different ways: 1) into your child theme and rename it `woocommerce-wishlists`… or… 2) into your child theme, inside `woocommerce` folder and rename it simply `wish lists`. To see if it's working you need to alter some template that your website is using in point 1 and in point 2… I have open a ticket… i will tell you when they will answer me.

Comment: Thank you for your patience in working with me. I've tried both of these solutions as well as a few other naming conventions to see if they'd work. No luck yet.

Comment: I had the same reply from WooThemes than you. I have made them a hot reply… :) … So the only **way is to alter templates inside the plugin**. When you are done with your changes, make a copy of the templates folder somewhere else, like this when plugin is updated, you can replace them easily… Sorry

Comment: Well, I thank you for trying, and especially for a hot reply. ;]
Definitely frustrating! Thanks for your attempts! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Make a copy of the template file you want to alter ( the wishlist plugin's template files are in plugins >> woocommerce-wishlists >> templates ).

Then inside your the main folder of whatever your active theme is, make a "woocommerce" folder. If you have customized any of the core Woocommerce templates, you should already have this folder. Drop the copy of the Wishlist template into this folder and edit it as you like. It should be in the root of your theme's "woocommerce" folder, not in any subfolder of it.

The Wishlists plugin actually uses the regular Woocommerce function to look for a template -- wc_get_template() -- so it should first look to the theme for a template and then if it doesn't find one, it looks to the default plugin templates.

I needed to do something similar with the Wishlists plugin, and this is working for me.